# R: Convert 3darray[i, j, ] to columns of df, fast and readable

Tags: arrays, r

I'm working with 3-dimensional arrays and want to have slices along the
third dimension for each position in the first two dimensions as columns in a data frame.
I also want my code to be readable for people who dont use R regularly.

Looping over the first two dimensions is very readable but slow (30 secs for the example below), while the permute-flatten-shape-to-matrix approach
is faster (14 secs) but not so readable.

Any suggestions for a nice solution?

## Reproducible example here:

```
# Create data
    d1 <- 200
    d2 <- 100
    d3 <- 50
    data <- array(rnorm(n=d1*d2*d3), dim=c(d1, d2, d3))

# Idea 1: Loop
    df <- data.frame(var1 = rep(0, d3))
    i <- 1

    system.time(
    for (c in 1:d2) { 
        for(r in 1:d1){
          i <- i + 1
          df[[i]] <- data[r, c, ]
        }
    })

# Idea 2: Permute dimension of array first
    df2 <- data.frame(var1 = rep(0, d3))

    system.time({
    data.perm <- aperm(data, c(3, 1, 2))
    df2[, 2:(d1*d2 + 1)] <- matrix(c(data.perm), nrow = d3, ncol = d1*d2)}
    )

    identical(df, df2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a much more simple approach:

```
t(apply(data, 3, c))
```

I hope it suits your expectations of being *fast* and *readable*.

- ***fast***, as demonstrated in the timings below.
- ***readable*** because it's a basic `apply` statement. All that is being done is using `c` to convert the `matrix` in each third dimension to a single vector in each third dimension, which then simplifies to a two-dimensional `array`. The result just needs to be `t`ransposed....

---

Here's your sample data:

```
set.seed(1)
d1 <- 200
d2 <- 100
d3 <- 50
data <- array(rnorm(n=d1*d2*d3), dim=c(d1, d2, d3))
```

Here are a few functions to compare:

```
funam <- function() t(apply(data, 3, c))
funrl <- function() {
  myl <- vector("list", d3)
  i <- 1

  for (c in 1:d2) { 
    for(r in 1:d1){
      i <- i + 1
      myl[[i]] <- data[r, c, ]
    }
  }
  do.call(cbind, myl)
}

funop <- function() {
  df <- data.frame(var1 = rep(0, d3))
  i <- 1

  for (c in 1:d2) { 
    for(r in 1:d1){
      i <- i + 1
      df[[i]] <- data[r, c, ]
    }
  }
  df[-1]
}
```

Here are the results of the timing:

```
system.time(am <- funam())
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.000   0.000   0.062 
system.time(rl <- funrl())
#    user  system elapsed 
#   3.980   0.000   1.375 
system.time(op <- funop())
#    user  system elapsed 
#  21.496   0.000  21.355
```

... and a comparison for equality:

```
all.equal(am, as.matrix(unname(op)), check.attributes = FALSE)
# [1] TRUE
all.equal(am, rl, check.attributes = FALSE)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Good job. I didn't think apply would pass as "readable" (I don't know who the third party audience is, really) so I stuck to a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea. Recommended read would be [The R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) by Patrick Burns (pun intended?).

```
myl <- vector("list", d3) #  create an empty list
i <- 1

system.time(
  for (c in 1:d2) { 
    for(r in 1:d1){
      i <- i + 1
      myl[[i]] <- data[r, c, ]
    }
  })

user  system elapsed 
 1.8     0.0     1.8 

# bind each list element into a matrix, column-wise
do.call("cbind", myl)[1:5, 1:5]

           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]        [,5]
[1,] -0.3394909  0.1266012 -0.4240452  0.2277654 -2.04943585
[2,]  1.6788653 -2.9381127  0.5781967 -0.7248759 -0.19482647
[3,] -0.6002371 -0.3132874  1.0895175 -0.2766891 -0.02109013
[4,]  0.5215603 -0.2805730 -1.0325867 -1.5373842 -0.14034565
[5,]  0.6063638  1.6027835  0.5711185  0.5410889 -1.77109124
```